# Why am i getting this error when trying to communicate with my server?

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments

I am simply trying to implement stripe payments in my app  and i am following the their doc here https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart and i keep getting this error ( Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:4242) , whenever i launch my app. I am not sure why this is happening i already tried adding        `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to my manifest file as some users suggested but to no avail.

```
public class payment_activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String paymentIntentClientSecret;
    private PaymentLauncher paymentLauncher;
    // we need paymentIntentClientSecret to start transaction
    private Button paymentButton;
    CardInputWidget cardInputWidget;

    private PaymentSheet paymentSheet;


    private static final String TAG = "CheckoutActivity";
    private static final String BACKEND_URL = "http://localhost:4242";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment);
        paymentButton = findViewById(R.id.payButton);
        cardInputWidget = findViewById(R.id.cardInputWidget);

        paymentSheet = new PaymentSheet(this, this::onPaymentSheetResult);

        fetchPaymentIntent();


        paymentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PaymentSheet.Configuration configuration = new PaymentSheet.Configuration("Example, Inc.");

                // Present Payment Sheet
                paymentSheet.presentWithPaymentIntent(paymentIntentClientSecret, configuration);
            }
        });


    }




    private void showAlert(String title, @Nullable String message) {
        runOnUiThread(() -> {
            AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(title)
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                    .create();
            dialog.show();
        });
    }

    private void showToast(String message) {
        runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());
    }

    private void fetchPaymentIntent() {
        final String shoppingCartContent = "{\"items\": [ {\"id\":\"xl-tshirt\"}]}";

        final RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(
                shoppingCartContent,
                MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8")
        );

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(BACKEND_URL + "/create-payment-intent")
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        new OkHttpClient()
                .newCall(request)
                .enqueue(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
                        showAlert("Failed to load data", "Error: " + e.toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(
                            @NonNull Call call,
                            @NonNull Response response
                    ) throws IOException {
                        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                            showAlert(
                                    "Failed to load page",
                                    "Error: " + response.toString()
                            );
                        } else {
                            final JSONObject responseJson = parseResponse(response.body());
                            paymentIntentClientSecret = responseJson.optString("clientSecret");
                            runOnUiThread(() -> paymentButton.setEnabled(true));
                            Log.i(TAG, "Retrieved PaymentIntent");
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private JSONObject parseResponse(ResponseBody responseBody) {
        if (responseBody != null) {
            try {
                return new JSONObject(responseBody.string());
            } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error parsing response", e);
            }
        }

        return new JSONObject();
    }

    private void onPaymentSheetResult(
            final PaymentSheetResult paymentSheetResult
    ) {
        if (paymentSheetResult instanceof PaymentSheetResult.Completed) {
            showToast("Payment complete!");
        } else if (paymentSheetResult instanceof PaymentSheetResult.Canceled) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Payment canceled!");
        } else if (paymentSheetResult instanceof PaymentSheetResult.Failed) {
            Throwable error = ((PaymentSheetResult.Failed) paymentSheetResult).getError();
            showAlert("Payment failed", error.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }




}


Faild to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:4242
```

Comment: Why do yo use port 4242? Try 5000 or above

Comment: @OlauPla because it says so in their documentation. Do you think you can just pick the port?

Comment: Yeah, i have to use 4242. It does not let me pick the port.

Comment: Do you know what `localhost` means and why this won't work this way in your app?

Comment: Oh sorry i thought you could pick the port and i have never seen in localhosting port 4242

Comment: @OlauPla but you have seen all the ports that are "5000 or above"?

Comment: When you localhost? Yes I only seen ports of 5000 or above like 8080

Comment: No, idk what it meant 10 seconds ago, but now that i googled it ik it refers to the current device used to access it. So i am guessing local host can't be used for my phone. So how do i go about fixing this?

Comment: Where are you running your app? And if you want to access it with your phone you must be on the same LAN network and host it so it listens to all ip's

Comment: @ArronLapta you need to connect to the machine that is running this ruby software. So replace the `localhost` part in the url with the IP of the machine where that is running. And your app needs to be able to reach that machine.

Comment: @OlauPla you can use any port above 1024 for any of your sockets in your applications.

Comment: How do i do this? I am just following the docs, on their site and local host is what the documentation provided so i am not sure how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I connect to `localhost:4242` in my Android apps using the following URL inside Android Studio: `http://10.0.2.2:4242`

Update your `BACKEND_URL` constant and give that a try.